# Unable to find REST API documentation for classic compute on AzureRM

Tags: azure

I am having hard time finding documentation for Classic compute on AzureRM. I was able to find documentation for compute on both Classic and Azure RM but not for classic compute on AzureRM. I know that the API exists since i have a sample method that works but i need to know all the available API calls to complete automation.

Does any one have documentation for https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{}/resourceGroups/{}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute?

Below is the sample call that works for our cloud service https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{}/resourceGroups/{}/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/{}/deploymentslots/Production?api-version=2015-06-01

I was able to find the below documentation from online which doesn't work for me since our services are in mixed state Classic available online- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloudservices/rest-get-deployment Compute available online- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get

Answer (score 3):

You can always "reverse engineer" it. I dont know if its supported, but I've been using different automation bits using ARM apis against ASM resources and its much better than having to use ASM cmdlets.

3 main ways to get data:

1. Run ASM command with `-debug` and\or fiddler and extract the API call
2. Run `Get-AzureRmProviderOperation -OperationSearchString 'microsoft.classiccompute/*'` will give you all the api calls available to the classiccompute api and you can use `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction` to invoke those (and you can use `-debug`\Fiddler here as well).
3. Perform portal action and capture api calls with fiddler

Answer (score 1):

The `ClassicCompute` API is intend for Azure Portal use only. The team has no plan to publish schema or document for these APIs.

The compute client does not support `ClassicCompute` Resource type since the compute client is designed to work for the new Compute Resource Type.

You could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/573), Azure Team has replied to it,

> Thanks for the feedback. We recommend that you manage ARM and ASM types separately . Both are fundamentally different from each other and we recommend everyone to move to the ARM model. We have no plan to support both with one set of API.

Besides, if it is possible, you could try to migrate classic VMs to ARM VMs, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-ps?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json).